# Antidifferentiation

Tags: real-analysis

I need a hint on how to start find the solutions to two integrals:

$\int_{0}^x t \sqrt{at+b} dt, a,b  \geq 0$ and

$\int_{0}^1{\sqrt{x}} / (1+\sqrt{x}) dx$.

I am only allowed to use integration by parts and change of variable. I am totally stuck. I have tried just about every substitution that I can think of... I must have made an error at some point, and not have caught it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first integral, try $u=at+b$. For the second, $y=\sqrt x+1$.

Added: If $u=at+b$, then you have that $t=\dfrac{u-b}{a}$. (I'll omit the limits below)
$$\int t\sqrt{at+b}\,dt=\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{u-b}{a}\sqrt u\,du$$
If $y=\sqrt x+1$, then $\sqrt x=y-1$, and $dx=2(y-1)\,dy$, so yo have
$$\int\frac{\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}\,dx=2\int\frac{(y-1)^2}{y}\,dy$$

Comment: I swear I have tried that... Is there a way you could post a couple steps?

Comment: THAT's I QUIT MATH!